# Nginx redirect *:port to subdomain

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm working with `Nginx`and I want to know how can I redirect all request with a specific port to a subdomain ?

This is my `default.conf` :

```
server{
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}

server{
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass   http://my-ip:8080;
        }
}
```

So with this I have the default `mydomain.com` serve the html folder, and a subdomain `blog.mydomain.com` serve an application running port 8080.

My problem is when I try to access directly `my-ip:8080`, or `mydomain.com:8080` or `blog.mydomain.com:8080` the server serve the application running port 8080 and I want to redirect all these requests to `blog.mydomain.com` without the `:8080`.

How can I do that ? Automatically redirect to `blog.mydomain.com` if I specify `:8080` in the url ?

Comment: You solved the problem? Our answers were helpful?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `my-ip:8080` or `mydomain.com:8080`, you call directly your application, not nginx. The issue I see here is not "my webapp doesn't redirect to nginx" but "I have a proxy but my webapp is directly accessible from the internet".

A clean way to fix it is to hide your application from the internet and let nginx be the only way to contact it. Configure your application to listen on `localhost` (it looks like it listens on `*` or `0.0.0.0`, meaning all interfaces). Then, tell nginx to proxy requests to `http://localhost:8080;`.

---

If you really want to keep your application listening on  `*:8080`, you can add a HTTP header in nginx (like `X-Forwarded-For` with `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`) and detect it in your application. Without it, redirect to nginx. Note that anyone can add HTTP headers...

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions for your problem:

If you can change code of application then you can handle HTTP request in application. You should be able get information about port from headers.

If you cannot change code of application but you can change port on which application is listening, then you can do redirect in nginx. To do this, you need start listening on port 8080 in nginx and redirect it to 80, and on 80 port you change `proxy_pass` to new port of application.